# How to span every 6th element full row, in a 3X3 grid in css?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am setting up a 3 X N grid of images, that need to have a banner that spans the entire column in every 6,9th,... positions.

But while setting the span, I want the remaining white space to be filled.

I tried to add `grid-auto-flow: dense` but it does not put the images in the correct order.

Below is the code :

```css
.grid { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  align-items: start;
  justify-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 540px;
  }
.grid img {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  max-width: 100%;
}
.grid img:nth-child(6) {
  grid-column: span 3;
  }
```

```html
<main class="grid">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533035353720-f1c6a75cd8ab?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="Sample photo">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547149600-a6cdf8fce60c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="Sample photo">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533035353720-f1c6a75cd8ab?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="Sample photo">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547149600-a6cdf8fce60c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="Sample photo">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533035353720-f1c6a75cd8ab?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="Sample photo">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547149600-a6cdf8fce60c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="Sample photo">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1555181937-efe4e074a301?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="Sample photo">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547149600-a6cdf8fce60c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="Sample photo">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533035353720-f1c6a75cd8ab?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="Sample photo">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547149600-a6cdf8fce60c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="Sample photo">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533035353720-f1c6a75cd8ab?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="Sample photo">
</main>
```

Here is the codepen link : [My Grid Example](https://codepen.io/Sidd92/pen/mddxKOd)

I want to have a grid of images where each row is filled with just the 6,9th... images spanning across the columns. I don't want to get white spaces in between. Currently, I am getting white space in the 5th element.

How do I get it incorrect order and display it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your selector like this: **`.grid img:nth-child(7n + 7) {`**

It will select every `7n + 7` as the result first 6 elements will be 3 in row and next element will take 100% of the space

Comment: Thank you but, it only works if i have 10 elements, if i add more , then the same issue is repeated. My total number of images will be dynamic so how do i make it same for all the images.  I edited the code and added a few more images in this (https://codepen.io/Sidd92/pen/mddxKOd).

Comment: @SiddharthVishvanath. You are right. I have edited my answer. Use `7n + 7`

Comment: @Arseniy-ll Thank you for the solution.